# Accesing query results in robot framework

Tags: python, database, robotframework

I am using databaselibrary to fetch multiple rows of data (on column each) to use for further testing. I need to be able to fetch the individual values for further use. Currently I am trying:

```
    ${Cardnumbers}=      query   SELECT card_num from xxxxxxxxx WHERE status = 
    'Issued' and ACTIVE_Flg = 'Y' and ROWNUM < 100
    Set Test Variable    ${Cardnumbers}
    ${Cardnumber} =  set test variable  ${Cardnumbers[0][1]}
    log   ${Cardnumber}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think this is how I proceeded on earlier cases, but now it is failig (saying that it can't find ${Cardnumbers[0][1]). The output of the query is:

```
   ${Cardnumbers} = [('2661999743484',), ('2661999743491',), ('2661999743507',), 
   ('2661999743514',), ('2661999743521',), ('2661999743538',), ('2661999743545',), 
   ('2661999743552',), ('2661999743569',), ('2661999743576',),...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are addressing a missing element from the tuple.
Try like this:

```
${Cardnumber} =  set test variable  ${Cardnumbers[0]}[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return a single column - `SELECT card_num from` , but you are trying to access a 2nd in the result.
Remember that the response - when it is already a python object - is a list of tuples: when accessing it, the first index will be the "row" in the response, the second - the "column".

So by typing `${Cardnumbers[0][1]}` you're effectively saying "Get me the value from the 1st row, and the 2nd column". Change it to `${Cardnumbers[0][0]}` (or `[4][0]`for the 5th row and so on, as long as the second index is 0) and it will work.

Comment: Thans for the suggestion, unfortunately is does not work when I put [0][0]

Comment: Ok, what does the error say with [0][0]?